# How to display name of user who wrote comment to post (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, blogs

I'm creating a blog on Rails with posts, users(authentication with Devise), comments. If user will write comment to post I want to show his name above his comment. How can I do this? Please, help me

My comments controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
def create
@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
@comment = @post.comments.build(params[:comment])
@comment.save
redirect_to @post
end

def destroy
@comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
@comment.destroy
redirect_to @comment.post
  end
end
```

My models:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :post_id, :text
belongs_to :post
belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy

validates :fullname,      :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
validates :password,      :presence => true
validates :email,         :presence => true, :uniqueness => true


devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :fullname
end


class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :text, :title, :tag_list
acts_as_taggable

validates :user_id, :presence => true
validates :title,   :presence => true
validates :text, :presence => true

belongs_to :user
has_many :comments
end
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just assign the user in `comments_controller.rb`

```
def create
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = @post.comments.build(params[:comment])
  @comment.user = current_user
  @comment.save
  redirect_to @post
end
```

Next time spend a little more time researching your question, this is a common task and a very brief Google search would have saved you the trouble of asking.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but after I did that, name of user beside comment is still empty. In my show file I use comment.user method. Is it right?

Comment: You're probably looking for <%= Comment.user.fullname %>

Comment: After all, it worked. I created a migration that add user_id to comments controller. Anyway, thanks for help